# Is there a listing of story arc episodes of Supernatural?

Tags: suggested-order, supernatural

I just started season 3, and I'm getting a bit tired of the "Monster of the Week" episodes, that don't further the main story arcs.  With several more seasons to go, I'm ready to start skipping episodes to get caught up.

What are the episodes I should watch if I only want to follow the main story arcs?

I'm okay with skipping episodes that provide background for sub-arcs, if they don't provide background for primary arcs.

Comment: Skip episodes? Egads! :-O

Comment: @ForceFlow Honestly, the first few seasons tend to drag, particularly when its just another haunting story (even if there is a "twist", like "the girl is a ghost, too!" or "it wasn't the serial killer's ghost after all!").  From the few spoilers I've seen, it seems like things get more interesting in later seasons (and I'm 6 seasons behind!), so yeah, I don't mind skipping episodes (especially given how little time I have to watch TV).

Comment: @Beofett Actually, I liked the first seasons better than the later ones with the big background stories, apocalypses etc.

Comment: Season 3 is when the "monster of the week" episodes start to taper off in favor of the "arc" episodes.  Not that there aren't still a fair amount of them.

Comment: Oh, I started taking a quick look at these to see how difficult it would be to make a list if one didn't already exist, and 1x12 reminded me - there's a handful of primary arcs, which I believe are what you're referring to in the question, but there's other sub-arcs, such as the events of 1x12 coming up _much_ later in the series, that IIRC are in "monster-of-the-week" episodes.  Do you care about those?

Comment: Also, other "monster-of-the-week" episodes that are retrospectively part of the primary arc.  I think about half of the "motw" episodes fall into that category, at least in these earlier seasons.  It's been quite a while, though.

Comment: @Izkata I'm okay with skipping episodes that provide background for sub-arcs, if they don't provide background for primary arcs.  It sounds like that would make for a more defined scope, anyway.

Comment: @Beofett You should add that detail to the question body. That specificity makes this way less broad.

Comment: @Keen Good point.  Done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure a list like that actually exists. After season one and two the focus on the overall story arc throughout every episode becomes much greater. Even in the M.O.T.W. episodes you'll be introduced to characters that will play a role in the story later on so my advice is to just watch them all.